# Cannot push a 2d array into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

Sorry if the title is unclear/badly worded, I'm a fairly new coder who sucks at remembering correct terminology. I have been trying to create a 3d array in Javascript that I want to look like this:

```js
var errorCountList = [
  [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  ],
  [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  ],
  [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  ]
];
```

However, I want the number of [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] lists in the 2d/3d parts of the list to be able to vary in length, if that makes any sense. So, as I result, I have been using a series of loops to push lists into a 2d array before pushing these 2d arrays into another array to make a 3d array.

```
for (count3 = 0; count3 < test.length; count3++)    {
        part2.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
    }
for (count5 = 0; count5 < restrictionValues.length; count5++)   {
        errorCountList.push(part2);
    }
```

with test and restrictionValues being changing list lengths. However, while when I print out the list using `print(JSON.stringify(errorCountList));` it visually appears the same as the errorCountList I set up, the values it displays after I run the rest of my code are radically different. How can I fix this issue? Thanks for the help in advance, this is my first time posting here so sorry about any issues in wording/formatting.

Comment: Please use the `[<>]` snippet editor to make a [mcve] and show us the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably pushing references of *one* array, rather than pushing nine different arrays. In order to save memory, javascript never creates a new array when reassigning an array (and the same goes with or objects).

You can see that in the log in the snippet below: `/**ref:2**/,`

```js
let part2 = [],
  errorCountList = [],
  restrictionValues = Array(3),
  test = Array(3);

for (let count3 = 0; count3 < test.length; count3++) {
  part2.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
}

for (let count5 = 0; count5 < restrictionValues.length; count5++) {
  errorCountList.push(part2);
}

console.log(errorCountList)
```

I would instead use a combination of `Array(n)`, to create an empty array, and `Array.fill(n)` to fill that empty array with zeroes.

```js
let errorCountList = [],
    restrictionValues = 3,
    maxLength = 6;

const FILLER = 0;

const random = (max, min = 1) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max + min);
};

for (let count5 = 0; count5 < restrictionValues; count5++) {
  errorCountList.push(Array( random(maxLength) ).fill(FILLER));
}

console.log(errorCountList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to *nest* the two `for` loops:

```js
test = [1, 2];
restrictionValues = [1, 2, 3];

errorCountList = [];
for (count5 = 0; count5 < restrictionValues.length; count5++) {
  part2 = [];
  for (count3 = 0; count3 < test.length; count3++) {
    part2.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
  }
  errorCountList.push([...part2]);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(errorCountList))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: If I may ask, what is the "..." for in the errorCountList.push([...part2]); code?

Comment: Using `[...part2]` makes a copy of the `part2` array. If you just push `part2` into the array using `errorCountList.push(part2)` you will get multiple references to the same array in `errorCountList` and then changing one of them will change all the others too...

Comment: Thank you for the help, pretty sure I would have been stuck on this part for at least a day or two without your help.